# Is there a way to remove the decoration ( underline ) of a hyperlink on an InfoPath form?

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

Is there a way to remove the decoration (underline) off a hyperlink on an InfoPath form?
I have a header that also serves as a link to relative data however it would look much better without the underline of a hyperlink. Is it possible to remove the "decoration" off a hyperlink by code or rule?